# How to make OnScroll animation Only with plain JavaScript and CSS.. Without using any library

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to know how to make OnScroll animation (like fade Up, fade Down, fade left etc.) using JavaScript and Css, without any libraries. I know there are lots of cool libraries that can help me to do them. Even I have used AOS for some projects but I wanted to know about more how it works in background.

**I wanted to know How to make OnScroll animation using plain JavaScript only. Without any libraries.**

Can Anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you  want  someone  to give  you  code or  do you want tutorials?

Comment: I can understand from a simple code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by utilizing CSS Animation, keyframes and Vanilla JavaScript.

You need to first decide how you want your element to be animated and then successfully create that animation within CSS.

**Within your CSS file**,

Create a unique class name just for the animation, then create the keyframes to go along with that animation. I've given a simple example within the snippet below.  Use this example for a better understanding of how to create the animation.  You can build upon that.  Notice the 0% and 100% keyframe states; this represents your starting and ending points of your animation. Once you successfully create the animation you want, you can then move onto JavaScript.

**Within JavaScript**,

1. set a variable for the elements you would like to animate.
2. create a function to determine where the element is relative to the client's on screen position.
3. add an event listener to listen for scroll events
4. finally, create a for loop to target the on screen element and then change the targeted elements class type to the animation class you made within your CSS.

Check out the snippet below for a working demo and to better understand the details behind each step.

```js
var words = document.querySelectorAll('.word');
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var isOutside = (rect.top >= window.innerHeight) || (rect.bottom <= 0);
  return !isOutside;
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    words[i].classList.toggle('in-view', isElementInViewport(words[i]));
}
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
   }
section {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.s1{
    background-color: skyblue;
}
.s2{
    background-color: rgb(82, 156, 185);
}
.s3{
    background-color: rgb(36, 107, 134);
}
.word{
    height: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.in-view{
    animation: slideRight .8s forwards .1s ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes slideRight{
0%{
    transform: translateX(-50vw);
    opacity: 0;
    
    }
100%{
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="s1">
        <svg class="in-view word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18.08 10.46">
            <path d="M41.45,32.59H39v-.88h6v.88H42.5v7.2h-1Z" transform="translate(-38.99 -31.71)"/>
            <path d="M50.24,36.84a2.83,2.83,0,0,1-2.89,3.08,2.76,2.76,0,0,1-2.78-3,2.84,2.84,0,0,1,2.88-3.09A2.75,2.75,0,0,1,50.24,36.84Zm-4.61.06c0,1.27.74,2.23,1.77,2.23s1.76-1,1.76-2.25c0-1-.49-2.23-1.74-2.23S45.63,35.8,45.63,36.9Z" transform="translate(-38.99 -31.71)"/>
            <path d="M51.58,35.88c0-.74,0-1.34,0-1.89h.94l.05,1h0a2.27,2.27,0,0,1,2.06-1.13c1.4,0,2.46,1.19,2.46,2.95,0,2.09-1.27,3.12-2.64,3.12A2,2,0,0,1,52.64,39h0v3.15h-1Zm1,1.55a2,2,0,0,0,.05.43,1.62,1.62,0,0,0,1.58,1.23c1.12,0,1.76-.91,1.76-2.24,0-1.16-.61-2.16-1.72-2.16A1.69,1.69,0,0,0,52.69,36a1.55,1.55,0,0,0-.07.43Z" transform="translate(-38.99 -31.71)"/>
        
       </svg>
    </section>
    <section class="s2">
        <svg class="word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 33.85 8.65">
        
              <path d="M46.72,36.24c-.06-1.13-.13-2.48-.12-3.49h0c-.28,1-.61,2-1,3.07l-1.43,3.92h-.79L42,35.89c-.38-1.14-.71-2.18-.93-3.14h0c0,1-.08,2.36-.15,3.57l-.22,3.47h-1l.56-8.08h1.33L43,35.62c.34,1,.61,1.88.82,2.72h0c.21-.82.49-1.7.85-2.72l1.44-3.91h1.33L48,39.79h-1Z" transform="translate(-39.7 -31.27)"/>
              <path d="M50.84,32.35a.65.65,0,1,1-1.3,0,.64.64,0,0,1,.66-.66A.62.62,0,0,1,50.84,32.35Zm-1.17,7.44V34h1v5.8Z" transform="translate(-39.7 -31.27)"/>
              <path d="M57.49,31.27v7c0,.52,0,1.1,0,1.5h-.95l-.05-1h0a2.15,2.15,0,0,1-2,1.14c-1.41,0-2.48-1.19-2.48-3,0-1.93,1.18-3.12,2.6-3.12a1.93,1.93,0,0,1,1.75.89h0V31.27Zm-1.06,5.08a1.77,1.77,0,0,0,0-.45,1.54,1.54,0,0,0-1.52-1.22c-1.09,0-1.74,1-1.74,2.24s.58,2.15,1.72,2.15a1.58,1.58,0,0,0,1.54-1.26,1.64,1.64,0,0,0,0-.45Z" transform="translate(-39.7 -31.27)"/>
              <path d="M64.26,31.27v7c0,.52,0,1.1,0,1.5h-.94l0-1h0a2.13,2.13,0,0,1-2,1.14c-1.41,0-2.49-1.19-2.49-3,0-1.93,1.19-3.12,2.61-3.12a2,2,0,0,1,1.75.89h0V31.27ZM63.2,36.35a1.77,1.77,0,0,0-.05-.45,1.54,1.54,0,0,0-1.52-1.22c-1.09,0-1.74,1-1.74,2.24s.58,2.15,1.72,2.15a1.59,1.59,0,0,0,1.54-1.26,1.64,1.64,0,0,0,.05-.45Z" transform="translate(-39.7 -31.27)"/>
              <path d="M66,31.27h1.06v8.52H66Z" transform="translate(-39.7 -31.27)"/>
              <path d="M69.43,37.08a1.86,1.86,0,0,0,2,2,3.8,3.8,0,0,0,1.61-.3l.18.76a4.67,4.67,0,0,1-1.93.36A2.7,2.7,0,0,1,68.42,37c0-1.75,1-3.13,2.73-3.13a2.46,2.46,0,0,1,2.39,2.74,4.88,4.88,0,0,1,0,.49Zm3.1-.76a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.47-1.71,1.76,1.76,0,0,0-1.62,1.71Z" transform="translate(-39.7 -31.27)"/>
            
          </svg>
    </section>
    <section class="s3">
        <svg class="word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 35.85 8.28">
            <path d="M39.91,31.81a10.82,10.82,0,0,1,1.91-.16,3.41,3.41,0,0,1,2.22.58,1.72,1.72,0,0,1,.67,1.43,1.94,1.94,0,0,1-1.37,1.78v0a2.08,2.08,0,0,1,1.67,2,2.22,2.22,0,0,1-.68,1.62,4.12,4.12,0,0,1-2.8.75,14.11,14.11,0,0,1-1.62-.09ZM41,35.12h.94c1.11,0,1.75-.57,1.75-1.35,0-1-.72-1.32-1.77-1.32a4.9,4.9,0,0,0-.92.07ZM41,39a6.25,6.25,0,0,0,.87,0c1.08,0,2.08-.4,2.08-1.57s-.95-1.56-2.09-1.56H41Z" transform="translate(-39.91 -31.65)"/>
            <path d="M51.68,36.84a2.83,2.83,0,0,1-2.89,3.08,2.76,2.76,0,0,1-2.78-3,2.84,2.84,0,0,1,2.88-3.09A2.75,2.75,0,0,1,51.68,36.84Zm-4.61.06c0,1.27.74,2.23,1.77,2.23s1.76-1,1.76-2.25c0-1-.49-2.23-1.74-2.23S47.07,35.8,47.07,36.9Z" transform="translate(-39.91 -31.65)"/>
            <path d="M54.29,32.32V34H55.8v.8H54.29v3.13c0,.72.2,1.13.79,1.13a2.13,2.13,0,0,0,.61-.08l.05.8a2.73,2.73,0,0,1-.94.14,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.14-.44A2.17,2.17,0,0,1,53.25,38V34.79h-.89V34h.89v-1.4Z" transform="translate(-39.91 -31.65)"/>
            <path d="M58.26,32.32V34h1.51v.8H58.26v3.13c0,.72.2,1.13.79,1.13a2.08,2.08,0,0,0,.61-.08l.05.8a2.69,2.69,0,0,1-.94.14,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.14-.44,2.17,2.17,0,0,1-.4-1.51V34.79h-.9V34h.9v-1.4Z" transform="translate(-39.91 -31.65)"/>
            <path d="M66.14,36.84a2.83,2.83,0,0,1-2.89,3.08,2.76,2.76,0,0,1-2.78-3,2.84,2.84,0,0,1,2.88-3.09A2.75,2.75,0,0,1,66.14,36.84Zm-4.6.06c0,1.27.73,2.23,1.76,2.23s1.76-1,1.76-2.25c0-1-.49-2.23-1.74-2.23S61.54,35.8,61.54,36.9Z" transform="translate(-39.91 -31.65)"/>
            <path d="M67.48,35.56c0-.6,0-1.1,0-1.57h.92l.05.93h0a2,2,0,0,1,1.83-1.07A1.71,1.71,0,0,1,71.9,35h0a2.35,2.35,0,0,1,.65-.76,2,2,0,0,1,1.29-.41c.76,0,1.9.51,1.9,2.52v3.42h-1V36.5c0-1.11-.41-1.78-1.26-1.78a1.36,1.36,0,0,0-1.25,1,2,2,0,0,0-.08.52v3.59h-1V36.31c0-.92-.41-1.59-1.21-1.59a1.44,1.44,0,0,0-1.31,1.05,1.49,1.49,0,0,0-.08.52v3.5h-1Z" transform="translate(-39.91 -31.65)"/>
        </svg>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)